# Is it possible to put in a atoomnumber and out a atoomname in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code i already attempted but it didnt work out:

This code is made by a 14 year old boy (me) so dont worry about the maintenance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AAPNE berekenen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title" id="title">Dit zijn de resultaten:</h1>
    <form id="Form">
        Atoomnummer: <br>
        <input  id="Atoomnummer" type="text" placeholder="Type the Atoomnumber"> <br>
        Massa: <br>
        <input id="Massa" type="text" placeholder="Type the massa of the atoom"> <br>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="berekenen();" >Bereken atoom</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="Writing();" >Krijg antwoorden</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(145, 248, 248, 0.562);
    border: 2px solid black;
}
button {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}
input {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var Atoomnaam;
var Atoomnummer;
var Protonen;
var Neutronen;
var Elektronen;
var TextInput;
var index;
var Naam = [
    "Calcium(Ca)","Scandium(Se)","Titaan(Ti)","Vanadium(V)","Chroom(Cr)","Mangaan(Mn)","Ijzer(Fe)","Kobalt(Co)"
    ,"Nikkel(Ni)","Koper(Cu)","Zink(Zn)","Galium(Ga)","Germanium(Ge)","Arseen(As)","Seleen(Se)","Broom(Br)","Krypton(Kr)","Rubidium(Rb)","Strontium(Sr)","Yttrium(Y)","Zirkonium(Zr)","Niobium(Nb)"
    ,"Molybdeen(Mo)","Technetium(Te)","Ruthenium(Ru)","Rhodium(Rh)","Palladium(Pd)","Zilver(Ag)","Cadmiun(Cd)","Indium(In)","Tin(Sn)","Antimoon(Sb)","Telluur(Te)","Jood(I)","Xenon(Xe)"
    ,"Cesium(Cs)","barium(Ba)","lanthaan(La)","Cerium(Ce)","Praseodymium(Pr)","Neodymium(Nd)","Promethium(Pm)","Samarium(Sm)","Europium(Eu)","Gadolinium(Gd)","Terbium(Tb)","Dysprosium(Dy)"
    ,"Holium(Ho)","Erbium(Er)","Thulium(Tm)","Ytterbium(Yb)","Lutetium(Lu)","Halfnium(Hf)","Tantaal(Ta)","Wolfraam(W)","Renium(Re)","Osmiun(Os)","Iridium(Ir)","Platina(Pt)","Goud(Au)","Kwik(Hg)"
    ,"Thallium(Tl)","Lood(Pb)","Bismut(Bi)","Pololnium(Po)","Astaat(At)","Radon(Rn)","francium(Fr)","Radium(Ra)","Actinimiun(Ac)","Thorium(Th)","Protactinium(Pa)","Uraan(U)","Neptunium(Np)"
    ,"Plutonium(Pu)","Americium(Am)","Curium(Cm)","berkelium(Bk)","Californium(Cf)","Einsteinium(Es)","Fermium(Fm)","Menselevium(Md)","Nobelium(No)","Lawrencien(Lr)","Rutherfordium(Rf)"
    ,"Dubnium(Db)","Seaborgium(Sg)","Bohrium(Bh)","Hassium(Hs)","Meitnerium(Mt)","Darmstadtium(Ds)","Roentgenium(Rg)"];
var TempMassa;
var Massa;
var Temp1;
var Temp2;
var Temp3;
var AtoomNum;
function NaamOfAtoom (AtoomNum) {
    switch (AtoomNum) {
        case 0:
            Atoomnaam ="Dit molecuul bestaat niet";
            break;
        case 1:
            Atoomnaam = "Waterstof(H)"
        case 2:
            Atoomnaam = "Helium(He)";
            break;
        case 3:
            Atoomnaam = "Lithium(Li)";
            break;
        case 4:
            Atoomnaam = "Beryllium(Be)";
            break;
        case 5:
            Atoomnaam = "Boor(B)";
            break;
        case 6:
            Atoomnaam = "Koolstof(C)";
            break;
        case 7:
            Atoomnaam = "Stikstof(N)";
            break;
        case 8:
            Atoomnaam = "Zuurstof(O)";
            break;
        case 9:
            Atoomnaam = "Fluor(F)";
            break;
        case 10:
            Atoomnaam = "Neon(Ne)";
            break;
        case 11:
            Atoomnaam = "Natrium(Na)";
            break;
        case 12:
            Atoomnaam = "Magnesium(Mg)";
            break;
        case 13:
            Atoomnaam = "Aluminium(Al)";
            break;
        case 14:
            Atoomnaam = "Silicium(Si)";
            break;
        case 15:
            Atoomnaam = "Fosfor(P)";
            break;
        case 16:
            Atoomnaam = "Zwafel(S)";
            break;
        case 17:
            Atoomnaam = "Chloor(Cl)";
            break;
        case 18:
            Atoomnaam = "Argon(Ar)";
            break;
        case 19:
            Atoomnaam = "Kalium(K)"
    };
};

function berekenen () {
   Protonen = document.getElementById("Atoomnummer").value;
   AtoomNum = document.getElementById("Atoomnummer").value;
   Elektronen = document.getElementById("Atoomnummer").value;
   Massa = document.getElementById("Massa").value;
   Neutronen = Massa - Protonen;
}
function Writing() {
    console.log(Atoomnaam, AtoomNum, Atoomnummer);
    alert("Protoon(en) = " + Protonen + "," + " Neutroon(en) = " + Neutronen + "," + " Elektron(en) = " + Elektronen + "," + " Naam = " + Atoomnaam)
}
```

Disclaimer: Javascript isnt done yet but it doesnt work and i want it first working then i can do the rest of the atoms, Dont worry if you cant ready it, its writing in Dutch.

Comment: You're not calling the `NaamOfAtoom` function anywhere. What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I would use an array to set Atoomnaam instead of that big switch.

Comment: Yeah, it just needs put `NaamOfAtoom(AtoomNum)` inside that `berekenen()` function to fill that `Atoomnaam` variable.

Comment: @Kosonome I tryed that but i stil doesnt work as i should work, it stil says by name: undefined

Comment: @Triby that also doenst work, i already tryed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a plunker with a working solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/QyAglTqoVx8k5RhZbenV?p=preview

Yeah, it needs put `NaamOfAtoom(AtoomNum)` inside that `berekenen()` function to fill that `Atoomnaam` variable, and change the switch.

Basically, when you did that `switch`, the `case`s are numbers, but `AtoomNum` is a string (you can type letter also), so it didn't entered any case options.
So was equivalent to `12 === '12'` returning false. `switch` is strict comparing `===` instead of only `==`.

Adding a `parseInt(number)` solved `switch` part.